# No Network, not booting

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

**The Problem:** I had installed Ubuntu on a brand new laptop and was not getting a wifi connection. Upon clicking the network manager I saw that wifi was disabled, so I turned it back on and still no luck. After running the `rfkill list all` and saw that one of the devices listed, `acer-wireless` was soft blocked. I tried unblocking via `rfkill unblock all` which did not help much either. I also tried reinstalling/updating the drivers for my network card and nada. I also ran `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap` for diagnostics and got this -

```
hp_wmi                 16384  0
acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  8 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi
```

**The Solution:** As one poster was able to deduce, it was odd that I had a module called `acer-wireless` since I am on an HP laptop. Thus, they suggested I run the command `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` followed by `sudo rfkill unblock all` followed by `sudo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, and I was/am up and running. Big thanks to everyone who helped me, and if you are looking for an explanation of what was going on, check chili555's answer down below. Thanks again!

Comment: Let's start by diagnosing the wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all`  Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Wow... I have never seen a person with this many problems with Linux. You said that there wasn't a desktop enviroment when you installed Debian. What version of Debian did you install.  Did you get the "Small/minimal installation package or did you get the "Complete installation package"?

Comment: Yes, and this level of grief is not new to me. The last 3 times I tried to install Linux I experienced similar or similarly-crippling problems =/ Anyhoo, I installed the iso that pops up in the top right corner of the screen when you go to Debian.org, and I used rufus to put it on a flash drive.

Comment: I suspect that the `rfkill` is most of the problem. May we also see: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap` Please confirm that when you click the Network Manager icon, *Enable WiFi* is checked.

Comment: Updated the question. Im currently searching for the missing ucodes. It doesnt look like the drivers for this particular card are super common as of right now, though =/

Comment: Is your laptop an Acer or an HP??

Comment: you could try a different wifi network manager called wicd (called wicked)
It simplifies network setup by automatically detecting and connecting to wireless and wired networks. i think you can install it directly from the installation cd.'https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Wicd'

Comment: Wicd will not fix his soft block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have an HP laptop and not an Acer. Let's remove the *acer_wmi* module and see if the soft block is resolved.

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Now is your wireless working? If so, let's blacklist *acer-wmi*:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Now, let's install newer firmware:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working correctly.

EXPLANATION: Laptops need a small helper module to translate key presses into action; in your case, to turn on the wireless. Your HP laptop incorrectly loaded both *hp-wmi* and *acer-wmi*. Your symptom was this:

> The second entry (1, if you are counting =P ) was "acer-wireless" and
>   was soft blocked (but not hardblocked).

I suggested that you unload the module, `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` (-r for 'remove') and, if your wireless was working, to blacklist the module so that it doesn't again incorrectly reload on reboot.

The improved firmware, while probably helpful, had nothing to do with the soft-block.

Comment: I don't know how you did it, but you did it... thank you so much. For the sake of learning, could you possibly take a crack at explaining what was going wrong and why this fixed it? I dont mean to be a pain, but I want to be able to fix things myself if I run into a similar problem down the road or if someone else does. Thanks again, a million.

Comment: Please see my edit above. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour I suggest you ask an entirely new question about the boot problem.