# HP Pavillion x360, No WiFi

Tags: hp, iwlwifi

I just bought a HP Pavillion x360 11".

I run from a live USB. I wish to verify that it works before installing.

I see no WiFi networks. This is what I have found:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/a2dy3CV.jpg]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/8NgZOgr.jpg]

I have only tried one thing, which did not work:

```
echo "blacklist acer-wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d
```

I am not sure this had effect since I run live and can not restart.

How can I make WiFi work?

I have not used Ubuntu for a couple of years. Please give instructions as basically as possible.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I have also enabled proprietary drivers.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo8Je.jpg]

If I do the following it tells me "I am now off line" - but I was never on-line in the first place. 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mogen.jpg]

lspci:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGkef.jpg]

sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJq0q.jpg]

Comment: I would try connecting it to a Ethernet connection if you have one and then going to the additional drivers tool. It could very well be that there is one that is available that your local system doesn't know about.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I am on a trip and I can't access Ethernet connection.

Comment: If I knew what driver it was, maybe I could download it via my phone and somehow install it via USB flash disk?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. And there is no need to post text outputs as screenshots.

Comment: Done. Thank you. I am sorry, I don't know how to copy text without connection. So I take photo of screen.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? This adapter is supported by new versions of Ubuntu. But according to the screenshot kernel module is not loaded.

Comment: It is 16.04 LTS 64 bit / Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please add: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thank you, I can't tell you how much I appreciate. My Internet (via phone) is very poor right now, if I fall out it is just temporary. / I put Ubuntu down on the disk now. No longer live. Wifi networks still not visible. If you need some data repeated because of HDD installation, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest you try: `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` Check to see if the wireless is still hard-blocked: `rfkill list all` You have a wireless interface `wlo1` and if the hard-block is fixed, you should be able to connect.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! I make the command you suggest, restart network manager and WiFi works. It seems I must do this every time I start the computer. Can I put the two commands in some file that is executed at start up? Should you or I write an answer to this?

Comment: I will write an answer. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a well-known issue that some HP computers erroneously load the *acer-wmi* module which hard-blocks the wireless. Here is your evidence:

> 1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
>
> Soft blocked:no
>
> Hard blocked:yes

It is necessary to blacklist the module so it doesn't load on boot in the future:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

However, the module is still loaded and running until you remove it or reboot; let's unload it:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
```

Finally, after your hard-drive install, update the firmware:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Here is another example of the same case: [No Network, not booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781520/no-network-not-booting/781606#781606)