# WIFI on HP Pavilion Hard blocked

Tags: wireless, hp

firstly I know I've already posted a similar question however I have since downgraded to Ubuntu 16.4 LTS (as needed for the programs needed for coursework).

The issue I am having is that the wifi is Hard blocked and rfkilall ublock as no effect on this. I have tried to find an answer online and tried a variety of things with no progress being made so hopefully I can be helped here.

Hardware/software versions:

- Laptop: HP Pavillion x360
- Model: 11-n012na
- Ubuntu Version: 16.04.03 LTS

.

```
rfkill list all
---------------
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

.

```
sudo lshw -class network
------------------------
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0f0
   version: 00
   serial: 38:b1:db:a2:fc:85
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:90710000-9071ffff
```

.

```
lsmod | grep -e hp -e wmi
-----------------------------------
shpchp                 36864  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    77824  20 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
hp_wireless            16384  0
wmi                    16384  0
```

I will obviously be happy to supply any extra info, thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have a key on the keyboard to lock/unlock Wifi? If it is locked via the keyboard, then you will probably not be able to unlock it via software.

Comment: The only key I have is "aeroplane mode" which has no effect. When testing this only activates/deactivates "soft blocked" not "hard blocked" :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HP Pavillion x360, No WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790193/hp-pavillion-x360-no-wifi)

Comment: Taken a look but mine doesnt have the acer thing so the fix wouldnt work :/

Comment: He has the issue with "acer-wireless" where mine is with the bog standard "Wireless LAN"

Comment: sorry for my oversight. Does it change anything if you blacklist the WMI module? (because https://askubuntu.com/questions/790193/hp-pavillion-x360-no-wifi is talking about blacklisting acer-wmi). What about the firmware update mentioned there?

Comment: I've already black listed the "hp-wmi" file which was suggested somewhere which was meant to help but didnt :/

Comment: According to HP, there is a button to activate the Wifi (not marked as aeroplane mode) - please see page 5, item 9 of the hp user guide at [http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01856579.pdf](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01856579.pdf)

Comment: That manual isn't for my laptop, and I can assure you 100% that there is not button or switch for the WiFi. To further support this the WiFi does work on windows (I'm dual booting)